# Flash messages in Phoenix show module not found

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm attempting to recreate the Flash Messages guide in [Phoenix](http://www.phoenixframework.org/v0.7.2/docs/controllers) however I'm getting a error that states `undefined function: Phoenix.Controller.Flash.put/3 (module Phoenix.Controller.Flash is not available)`

[image: Phoenix module Flash is not available]

However:
I have the `plug :fetch_flash` in my router.ex browser pipeline.
I have included the:

```
use Phoenix.Controller
alias Phoenix.Controller.Flash
```

at the top of the module definition.
I'm also attempting to adapt the syntax to my code (where I receive a parameter in the render).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at a really old version of the documentation (for `v0.7.2`) The latest is `v0.14.0` and you want the following code:

```
conn
|> put_flash(:error, "Some Message")
|> put_flash(:info, "Another Message")
```

This change was made in [v0.8.0](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/ba51261478d93eacb1f5e83a1ba20a54f5bc6f71/CHANGELOG.md#v080-2015-01-11)

The correct docs for your version are available at https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/controllers.html#flash-messages

Comment: That was it. however messages are not being displayed, No errors are thrown.

Comment: Do you have something like `<p class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><%= get_flash(@conn, :info) %></p>` in your template?

Comment: Yes.
```<p class="alert alert-info" role="alert"><%= get_flash(@conn, :info) %></p>
      <p class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"><%= get_flash(@conn, :error) %></p>```

Comment: ```def index(conn, _params) do
  #Query that creates a table in the database
    table_create("contentText")
    |> Basedados.Database.run
      # List all elements of a table from the database
    q = table("contentText")
      |> Basedados.Database.run #Run the query through the database
    conn
    |> put_flash(:error, "Some Message")
    |> put_flash(:info, "Another Message")
    render conn, "index.html", contentText: q #Render users searched on the users template
  end
end```

Comment: This is difficult to read from the comments. Could you please attach your controller and template to your question.

Comment: I found the issue. In the documentation it's like ```|> render("index.html")```.
It should be ```|> render "index.html", contentText: q``` in my case